# How to replace several variables with several variables from another dataframe in R using a loop?

Tags: r, loops, replace, assign

I would like to replace multiple variables with variables from a second dataframe in R.

```
df1$var1 <- df2$var1
df1$var2 <- df2$var2

# and so on ...
```

As you can see the variable names are the same in both dataframes, however, numeric values are slightly different whereas the correct version is in df2 but needs to be in df1. I need to do this for many, many variables in a complex data set and wonder whether someone could help with a more efficient way to code this (possibly without using column references).

Here some example data:

```
# dataframe 1
var1 <- c(1:10)
var2 <- c(1:10)
df1 <- data.frame(var1,var2)

# dataframe 2
var1 <- c(11:20)
var2 <- c(11:20)
df2 <- data.frame(var1,var2)

# assigning correct values
df1$var1 <- df2$var1
df1$var2 <- df2$var2
```

Comment: Are both data frames same dimensions (same number of rows AND columns)? If so, why not simply use `df2` going forward. Maybe you should post *actual* data and issue as this seems too simplified. If different rows/cols consider `merge` on unique identifier then assign.

Comment: Thanks Parfait, sorry that this is so simplified. I am new here and wasn't sure how it "works"; df2 has only the variables I need to replace (so same rows, less colums as df1); I was thinking about `merge` as I have an ID variable but somehow thought that there might be a different way without having to rearrange the order of the df afterwards (and hence just replacing the values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Parfait has said, the current post seems a bit too simplified to give any immediate help but I will try and summarize what you may need for something like this to work.

If the assumption is that `df1` and `df2` have the same number of rows AND that their orders are already matching, then you can achieve this really easily by the following subset notation:

```
df1[,c({column names df1}), drop = FALSE] <- df2[, c({column names df2}), drop = FALSE]
```

Lets say that `df1` has columns `a`, `b`, and `c` and you want to replace `b` and `c` with two columns of `df1` whose columns are `x`, `y`, `z`.

```
df1[,c("b","c"), drop = FALSE] <- df2[, c("y", "z"), drop = FALSE]
```

Here we are replacing `b` with `y` and `c` with `z`. The `drop` argument is just for added protection against subsetting a data.frame to ensure you don't get a vector.

If you do NOT know the order is correct or one data frame may have a differing size than the other BUT there is a unique identifier between the two data.frames - then I would personally use a function that is designed for merging two data frames. Depending on your preference you can use `merge` from base or use `*_join` functions from the `dplyr` package (my preference).

```
library(dplyr)
#assuming a and x are unique identifiers that can be matched.
new_df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("a"="x"))
```

Comment: Thanks Justin! They do in fact have the same number of rows and the orders are matching so your comment and code was very useful!